# Trouble Import Android Project from Github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, pull-request

Let's say my project directory on Github looks like this

```
\root
    \Readme.md
    \Android Project I need to Import
        \app
        \and so on
```

Whenever I try to import this Git repository into Android Studio, I can't access my files because the Android project is a sub-directory. I can't clone the project from the command line because then Android Studio refuses to open it.

Has anyone else experienced this or knows what to do? I've been stuck for a few hours on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you just open the project from the subdirectory project root (you have labelled it as `Android Project`)?  Android Studio is basically just IntelliJ, and it should be able to open the project.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When I download it directly from Github, I can't perform any pull requests as the git log history is reset

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense.  Have you already cloned the repository, and if so how did you "download" the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `/root` has a `.gitmodules` file, which could indicate `Android Project` is a submodule.
Then `Android Project` would not have any `.git` in it, because the history would be managed by the parent folder.